# Issue with conflicting jQuery plugins?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use the Coda pop-up bubble and the myGlider in one page but they are conflicting and refuse to work together. I am fairly new to jQuery so I'm sure it's something simple that I just can't see.

Here's the meta include they're in:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script src="/js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/js/effects.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/js/glider.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/js/glider2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/sifr/sifr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/sifr/sifr-addons.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/autoBreadcrumbs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//hide the all of the element with class msg_body
$(".msg_body").hide();
//toggle the componenet with class msg_body
$(".msg_head").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).next(".msg_body").slideToggle(400);
});
$(".msg_head").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).next(".msg_body").slideToggle(400);
});
});
function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}
</script>
<script src="/SpryAssets/SpryCollapsiblePanel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/SpryAssets/SpryCollapsiblePanel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/glider.css" type="text/css" media="screen"         charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sifr/sIFR-screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sifr/sIFR-print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
<link href="/css/pagestyles-new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />


<script src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bubble.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bubble.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

I've tried re-arranging everything but it still doesn't work.  I believe they might both be calling on the a. class but after a lot of reading I'm still confused as hell as to how to change it! Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ummm, are you loading any version of jQuery before you are trying to execute your script? I cannot see any.

Comment: That's what I'm confused about! Bear in mind, this is an already created website that I have come into to make amends. All scripts are working and the other web guy says that myGlider has jquery integrated or something? I have tried adding the latest jquery above everything but it makes no difference.

Comment: I'd definitely leave the jQuery.js included as things like myGlider are usually plugins that rely on having jQuery loaded beforehand. At least I have never seen it included into a plugin (this would mess with people wanting to use more than one plugin). Also, do you have a JS-console that you can access to see if there are any errors thrown? Also, as you are using prototype simultaneously this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ might be also worth having a look at.